# How to get an element in json array of objects db2

Tags: sql, database, db2

DB2 - I'm trying to get an specific item of my json array of objects...
Given this value saved in my column **user_properites**:

```
{
   "properties":[
     { "key": "firstName", "value": "Jon" },
     { "key": "lastName", "value": "Doe" },
     { "key": "age", "value": 20 }
   ]
}
```

I'm using **JSON_QUERY** and I was doing something like:

```
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(u.user_properties, '$.properties[1]') AS lastName
FROM 
    USER u
```

But I need to get the lastName without pass the position on the array...
Is there a way to search an item by some value?
Thanks for the support :)

Comment: What version and platform of Db2? Please add this. In Db2 LUW 11.5 you have these JSON path expressions: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-sql-json-path-expression You might have issues because of the generic structure of your JSON object. Why don't you use {"lastName":"Doe"}...?

Comment: You may use generic [JSON_UNNEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035346/db2-nested-json/63042808?r=SearchResults&s=4|10.2432#63042808) table function. For your case: `SELECT T.DOC_ID, A.INDEX, IT.* 
FROM 
  TAB T
-- unnesting
, TABLE(UNNEST_JSON(T.DOC, '$.properties')) A
-- array element to row
, JSON_TABLE
  (
    A.ITEM, 'strict $' COLUMNS
    (
        KEY   VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.key'
      , VALUE VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.value' 
    ) ERROR ON ERROR
  ) IT`