# Can't extract an array from JSON using JSON_TABLE on DB2 v11.5

Tags: sql, json, db2

I have a table where I allocated a JSON document as string inside a CLOB field. Inside that JSON, there is an array that I need to expose as a table to can join in a SQL sentence.

Let me explain with an example: in the JSON below, I need to convert the array on a table of two cols (type and main) and two rows (same length of array) to can join with another table.field.

**Example JSON**

```
{
    "string":"string",
    "array":[{
        "type":"main",
        "name":"name"
    },{
        "type":"othertype",
        "name":"othername"
    }],
    "object":{
        "type":"objecttype",
        "name":"objectname"
    }
}
```

I read the official documentation and found that I can do that with JSON_TABLE function. The documentation have 2 different JSON_TABLE, one on built-in functions, SYSIBM package and the other one on SYSTOOLS package that seems to will be deprecated in future.

With SYSIBM.JSON_TABLE function I can extract from the JSON field properties such as string or string inside objects, but I can't extract the array as table rows (my main goal).

**Here is the SQL sentence I'm trying to do (I put the json as parameter to check but the final destination is on a table.field):**

```
select t.* 
from json_table('{"string":"string","array":[{"type":"main","name":"name"},{"type":"othertype","name":"othername"}],"object":{"type":"objecttype","name":"objectname"}}' FORMAT JSON, 
    'strict $' columns (
        string varchar(20) path 'strict $.string',
        type varchar(20) path 'strict $.object.type',
        name varchar(20) path 'strict $.object.name',
        nested path 'strict $.array[*]' columns(
            type2 varchar(20) path 'strict $.type',
            name2 varchar(20) path 'strict $.name'
        )
    ) error on error
) as t where true;
```

**The error I'm obtaining is:**

`SQL0104N  An unexpected token "path 'strict $.array[*]' columns(type2" was found following "object.name', nested".  Expected tokens may include:"<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601`

**The result expected:**

| string | type | name | type2 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | objecttype | objectname | main | name |
| string | objecttype | objectname | othertype | othername |

**If I change [*] clause for a specific index, ie. [0] works but only receive the first element in the array and throw an error if there is no elements:**

```
select t.* 
from json_table('{"string":"string","array":[{"type":"main","name":"name"},{"type":"othertype","name":"othername"}],"object":{"type":"objecttype","name":"objectname"}}' FORMAT JSON, 
    'strict $' columns (
        string varchar(20) path 'strict $.string',
        type varchar(20) path 'strict $.object.type',
        name varchar(20) path 'strict $.object.name',
        nested path 'strict $.array[1]' columns(
            type2 varchar(20) path 'strict $.type',
            name2 varchar(20) path 'strict $.name'
        )
    ) error on error
) as t where true;
```

| string | type | name | type2 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | objecttype | objectname | main | name |

**Also, if I remove the array specification from the SQL sentence it doesn't throw any error but obviously, I don't have the data I need:**

```
select t.* 
from json_table('{"string":"string","array":[{"type":"main","name":"name"},{"type":"othertype","name":"othername"}],"object":{"type":"objecttype","name":"objectname"}}' FORMAT JSON, 
    'strict $' columns (
        string varchar(20) path 'strict $.string',
        type varchar(20) path 'strict $.object.type',
        name varchar(20) path 'strict $.object.name'
    ) error on error
) as t where true;
```

**Result obtained:**

| string | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| string | objecttype | objectname |

**NOTE:** I also checked with SYSTOOLS.JSON_TABLE but it doesn't work as I wanted, and also need a BSON as main source instead of string and I don't want to make conversions each time I need to look inside.

**NOTE2:** Also, when I tried to put *null on error* instead of *error on error* (to return null values instead of errors) I received an error. The same happens when I change *strict* clause with *lax*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db2 for LUW (including current v11.5.8.0) doesn't support the `nested path` expression.
Look at the solution with a generic function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63042808/10418264).
In your case:

```
WITH TAB (DOC) AS 
(
VALUES
(
'{
    "string":"string",
    "array":[{
        "type":"main",
        "name":"name"
    },{
        "type":"othertype",
        "name":"othername"
    }],
    "object":{
        "type":"objecttype",
        "name":"objectname"
    }
}'
)
)
SELECT D.*, IT.* 
FROM 
  TAB T
, TABLE (UNNEST_JSON (T.DOC, '$.array')) A
-- array element to row
, JSON_TABLE
  (
    A.ITEM, 'strict $' COLUMNS
    (
        TYPE2 VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.type'
      , NAME2 VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name' 
    ) ERROR ON ERROR
  ) IT
-- other elements of original JSON to row
, JSON_TABLE
  (
    T.DOC, 'strict $' COLUMNS
    (
        STRING VARCHAR (20) PATH '$.string'
      , TYPE   VARCHAR (20) PATH '$.object.type'
      , NAME   VARCHAR (20) PATH '$.object.name'
    ) ERROR ON ERROR
  ) D
```

The result is:

| STRING | TYPE | NAME | TYPE2 | NAME2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | objecttype | objectname | main | name |
| string | objecttype | objectname | othertype | othername |

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark Barinstein. I'll check your solution.

I saw another answer from you on another question but without an alternative as you're doing now.  I really appreciate the effort you put in.

As I'm a newbie here, I can't upvote until I have enough reputation, but I'll do as soon as I have it.