CLOB - Queries json array with IN operator
I'm working with DB2 using a "data" column containing a JSON object stored as a CLOB.
To simplify my scenario consider this (easier) example:
CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    PrefMeal CLOB
);

INSERT INTO Students (StudentID, Name, PrefMeal) VALUES
(1, 'John Doe', '{"pizza":[{"id":2,"name":"Pizza Patate e Salsiccia","ingredients":["Potatoes","Mozzarella Cheese","Sausage"]}]}'),
(2, 'Jane Doe', '{"pizza":[{"id":1,"name":"Pizza Margherita","ingredients":["Tomato Sauce","Mozzarella Cheese","Oregano"]}]}'),
(3, 'Mario Rossi', '{"pizza":[{"id":2,"name":"Pizza Patate e Salsiccia","ingredients":["Potatoes","Mozzarella Cheese","Sausage"]},{"id":1,"name":"Pizza Margherita","ingredients":["Tomato Sauce","Mozzarella Cheese","Oregano"]}]}');

SELECT s.*
FROM Students s

Which of course returns all the students:
STUDENTID|NAME       |PREFMEAL                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        1|John Doe   |{"pizza":[{"id":2,"name":"Pizza Patate e Salsiccia","ingredients":["Potatoes","Mozzarella Cheese","Sausage"]}]}                                                                                                |
        2|Jane Doe   |{"pizza":[{"id":1,"name":"Pizza Margherita","ingredients":["Tomato Sauce","Mozzarella Cheese","Oregano"]}]}                                                                                                    |
        3|Mario Rossi|{"pizza":[{"id":2,"name":"Pizza Patate e Salsiccia","ingredients":["Potatoes","Mozzarella Cheese","Sausage"]},{"id":1,"name":"Pizza Margherita","ingredients":["Tomato Sauce","Mozzarella Cheese","Oregano"]}]}|

The Problem
Now, suppose that I would like to select all the students which have at least a "Pizza Margherita" as a prefered meal.
Normally an IN operator would make the magic but $.pizza is a JSON_ARRAY and the simpler solution does not works (so json path direct access too)...
I thought that I could use JSON_QUERY function to perform something similar to:
SELECT S.NAME, JSON_QUERY(S.PREFMEAL, '$.pizza[*].name' WITH CONDITIONAL WRAPPER) AS PREF_PIZZA
FROM STUDENTS s
WHERE JSON_QUERY(S.PREFMEAL, '$.pizza[*].name') IN ('Pizza Margherita');

Which of course does not return any rows since JSON_ARRAY and IN operators works differently rather than a simpler ARRAY.
The only solution I've found so far is the following one, which of course is not feasible for some IN comparison (too expensive/long):
I don't like the only "solution" I've found so far (it's more a workaround tbh), which I think it's not feasible and too expensive in cost and length of the query (multiple values in IN would be trasformed in many OR conditions):
SELECT *
FROM STUDENTS s
WHERE (JSON_QUERY(S.PREFMEAL, '$.pizza.name' WITH CONDITIONAL WRAPPER)) LIKE ('%"Pizza Margherita"%')

That returns correctly:
STUDENTID|NAME       |PREFMEAL                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        2|Jane Doe   |{"pizza":[{"id":1,"name":"Pizza Margherita","ingredients":["Tomato Sauce","Mozzarella Cheese","Oregano"]}]}                                                                                                    |
        3|Mario Rossi|{"pizza":[{"id":2,"name":"Pizza Patate e Salsiccia","ingredients":["Potatoes","Mozzarella Cheese","Sausage"]},{"id":1,"name":"Pizza Margherita","ingredients":["Tomato Sauce","Mozzarella Cheese","Oregano"]}]}|

I'm running out of ideas, I've even tried with JSON_TABLE but can't find a way to properly use it in the Where clause.
Any help will be appreciated!

Have you tried JSON_TABLE instead of JSON_QUERY?

Yup, the problem (from what I've got so far) is that you can't produce more rows for a single column value using JSON_TABLE (thus unnesting it) since you are forced to use "strict $". So the problem is almost the same.
Here it's an example:
FROM Students S,
     JSON_TABLE(S.PREFMEAL, 'strict $'
      COLUMNS( PIZZAS VARCHAR(100) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.pizza.name' WITH CONDITIONAL WRAPPER) ERROR ON ERROR) AS JT```


Which returns  something like 

`3 Mario Rossi ["Pizza Patate e Salsiccia","Pizza Margherita"]`

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76480819/cant-extract-an-array-from-json-using-json-table-on-db2-v11-5

Thank you Henrik, I've checked this answer but It seems not so optimized, right? I guess this is the only way but it hurts so much : /

There is a difference between SQL statement, access plan, and actual runtime. Have you tried it? I come from XML and would love to see XMLTABLE capabilities...

I just can second Henrik. A BLOB is a BLOB, and if it is 2GB in length your runtime is subobtimal. If you unnest your JSON to a table, Db2 has better methods to access the columns wanted in larger scenarios.

After all, I agree with you guys, even because with LIKE used in that way I could not leverage on indexes so the performances could be worse.
Anyway, I can't believe that for DB2 LUW JSON_TABLE does not handle unnesting (while DB2 for i-series does).
Thanks for the support you all :)
