# Get value from JSON Array List in DB2

Tags: sql, json, db2, json-table

Below is example kind of data. Is there any way to get value only **id** from below json array.

> **Env**: DB2 query **TABLE NAME**: RTN_PRD **COLUMN NAME** : DTL_PRD

`{"ProductList":"[{\"ID\":\"1111\",\"Product\":\"A001\"} ,{\"ID\":\"222\",\"Product\":\"A002\"} ,{\"ID\":\"333\",\"Product\":\"A003\"}]"}`

I have tried below solution, but error.

```
SELECT 
 P.ID_PROD
FROM 
RTN_PRD,
JSON_TABLE 
( JSON_VALUE ( DTL_PRD,'$.ProductList[*]' )
    COLUMNS (
         ID_PROD  varchar (100) PATH '$.ID')
) P
```

Comment: Some mandatory syntax element (`'strict $'`, `error on error`) are [missing](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-json-table), but DB2LUW does not provide a simple way to extract data from JSON arrays. You can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035346/db2-nested-json/63042808#63042808). If you are using DB2 for Z/OS maybe this will work too. With DB2 for IBMi you can use [nested path clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-json-table)

Answer (score 0):

DB2 for LUW solution.
Using one of the generic UDFs provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63042808/10418264).

```
WITH RTN_PRD (DTL_PRD) AS 
(
VALUES '{"ProductList":
[
  {"ID":"111", "Product":"A001"} 
, {"ID":"222", "Product":"A002"}
, {"ID":"333", "Product":"A003"}
]
}'
)
SELECT T.ITEM, JSON_QUERY (T.ITEM, '$.ID') AS ID
FROM 
  RTN_PRD R
, TABLE (UNNEST_JSON (R.DTL_PRD, '$.ProductList')) T
```

The result is:

| ITEM | ID |
| --- | --- |
| "{ "ID" : "111", "Product" : "A001" }" | "111" |
| "{ "ID" : "222", "Product" : "A002" }" | "222" |
| "{ "ID" : "333", "Product" : "A003" }" | "333" |